# How to get data from Mariadb database to table via JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Began to learn the Java language. I really liked the Scene Builder technology. I'm trying to display a table from the MariaDB database in the GUI, but I get an error that could not be resolved. Help please, if you understand. I dropped the code completely.

**Main.java**

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application  {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("view/FXMLSample.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 640,480);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("User list");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**controller/Controller.java**

```
package sample.controller;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import sample.model.Person;
import sample.model.ConnectDB;

import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;

import java.sql.*;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;

    private ObservableList<Person> usersData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @FXML
    private TableView<Person> tableUsers;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, Integer> idColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> usernameColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> firstnameColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> lastnameColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> emailColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> genderColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> descColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> createdonColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> editedonColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> activeColumn;

    @FXML
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        conn = ConnectDB.ConnectMariaDB();
        initData();

        tableUsers.setItems(usersData);

    }

    private void initData(ActionEvent event) throws SQLException {

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM test";
        rs = pst.executeQuery(sql);

        if(rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getInt("id");
            String username = rs.getString("username");
            String firstname = rs.getString("firstname");
            String lastname = rs.getString("lastname");
            String email = rs.getString("email");
            String gender = rs.getString("gender");
            String description = rs.getString("description");
            String createdon = rs.getString("createdon");
            String editedon = rs.getString("editedon");
            String active = rs.getString("active");
            usersData.add(new Person(id, username, firstname, lastname, email, gender, description, createdon, editedon, active));
        }


    }


}
```

**model/ConnectDB.java**

```
package sample.model;

import java.sql.*;

public class ConnectDB {

    Connection conn = null;

    public static Connection ConnectMariaDB() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://localhost/test_new","root","123456");
            System.out.println("Connection success!");
            return conn;
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**model/Person.java**

```
package sample.model;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class Person {

    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    private String gender;
    private String description;
    private String createdon;
    private String editedon;
    private String active;

    public Person(int id, String username, String firstname, String lastname, String email, String gender, String description, String createdon, String editedon, String active) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.email = email;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.description = description;
        this.createdon = createdon;
        this.editedon = editedon;
        this.active = active;
    }

    public Person() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getCreatedon() {
        return createdon;
    }

    public void setCreatedon(String createdon) {
        this.createdon = createdon;
    }

    public String getEditedon() {
        return editedon;
    }

    public void setEditedon(String editedon) {
        this.editedon = editedon;
    }

    public String getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(String active) {
        this.active = active;
    }
}
```

**view/FXMLSample.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<VBox prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="640.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.controller.Controller">
  <children>
    <MenuBar VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
      <menus>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="New" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Open…" />
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Open Recent" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save As…" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Revert" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Preferences…" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Quit" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Undo" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Redo" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Cut" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Copy" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Paste" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Select All" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Unselect All" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About MyHelloApp" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
      </menus>
    </MenuBar>
    <AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-1.0" maxWidth="-1.0" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2">
         <children>
            <Label layoutX="20.0" layoutY="14.0" text="Table" />
            <TableView fx:id="tableUsers" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="37.0" prefHeight="285.0" prefWidth="600.0">
              <columns>
                  <TableColumn prefWidth="42.0" text="ID" fx:id="idColumn" />
                  <TableColumn prefWidth="67.0" text="Username" fx:id="usernameColumn" />
                  <TableColumn prefWidth="156.0" text="Fullname">
                     <columns>
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="First name" fx:id="firstnameColumn" />
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Last name" fx:id="lastnameColumn" />
                     </columns>
                  </TableColumn>
                <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="E-mail" fx:id="emailColumn" />
                <TableColumn prefWidth="69.0" text="Gender" fx:id="genderColumn" />
                  <TableColumn prefWidth="69.0" text="Description" fx:id="descColumn" />
                  <TableColumn prefWidth="63.0" text="Created" fx:id="createdonColumn" />
                  <TableColumn minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="57.0" text="Edited" fx:id="editedonColumn" />
                  <TableColumn minWidth="4.0" prefWidth="105.0" text="Active" fx:id="activeColumn" />
              </columns>
            </TableView>
            <Button layoutX="23.0" layoutY="336.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Create" />
            <Button layoutX="88.0" layoutY="336.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Update" />
            <Button layoutX="154.0" layoutY="336.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            <Button layoutX="219.0" layoutY="336.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Refresh" />
         </children>
    </AnchorPane>
  </children>
</VBox>
```

**Error:**

> Error:(64, 9) java: method initData in class sample.controller.Controller cannot be applied to given types;
>     required: javafx.event.ActionEvent
>     found: no arguments
>     reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Did now like this

```
private void initData() throws SQLException {
...
}
```

and also

```
@FXML
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        conn = ConnectDB.ConnectMariaDB();
        try {
            initData();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        tableUsers.setItems(usersData);

    }
```

In the end, I gave an error.

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin\java.exe"
>   "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition
>   2019.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=50017:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath
>   "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Projects\JavaFXTest\out\production\JavaFXTest;C:\Users\ccpraktikant\Downloads\mariadb-java-client-2.4.1.jar"
>   sample.Main Connection success! Exception in Application start method
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start
>   method    at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$159(LauncherImpl.java:182)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
>   /C:/Projects/JavaFXTest/out/production/JavaFXTest/sample/view/FXMLSample.fxml
>
> at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)    at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)     at
>   sample.Main.start(Main.java:13)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$166(LauncherImpl.java:863)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$179(PlatformImpl.java:326)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$177(PlatformImpl.java:295)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$178(PlatformImpl.java:294)
>     at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)  at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$152(WinApplication.java:177)
>     ... 1 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   sample.controller.Controller.initData(Controller.java:77)     at
>   sample.controller.Controller.initialize(Controller.java:65)   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)     ... 17 more
>   Exception running application sample.Main
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at

`initData();`

and your method,

```
private void initData(ActionEvent event) throws SQLException {
```

the method takes parameters and your call does not have any parameters.

I suggest you rewrite your method to take no parameters.

```
private void initData() throws SQLException {
```

Comment: Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'JavaFXTest'
Information:javac 1.8.0_211 was used to compile java sources
Information:26.04.2019 08:29 - Build completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 3 s 609 ms
C:\Projects\JavaFXTest\src\sample\controller\Controller.java
Error:(64, 17) java: unreported exception java.sql.SQLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Comment: If you remove the parameter comes out such an error.

Comment: Did now like this

`private void initData() throws SQLException {`

and also

`@FXML
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        conn = ConnectDB.ConnectMariaDB();
        try {
            initData();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        tableUsers.setItems(usersData);

    }`

Comment: Good job at figuring your new problem out. If my answer helped you with your original problem, you should have excepted it as the correct solution. If you experienced a new problem after updating your code using this answer, you should have asked a new question. StackOverflow tries to avoid evolving/dynamic questions.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the controller as follows and it all worked.

**controller/Controller.java**

```
package sample.controller;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import sample.model.Person;
import sample.model.ConnectDB;

import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;

import java.sql.*;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Statement st = null;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private TableView<Person> tableUsers;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, Integer> idColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> usernameColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> firstnameColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> lastnameColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> emailColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> genderColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> descColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> createdonColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> editedonColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> activeColumn;

    @FXML
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        conn = ConnectDB.ConnectMariaDB();

        final ObservableList data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        String query = "SELECT * FROM test";

        Statement st = null;
        try {
            st = conn.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Person person;

        try {
            while (rs.next()) {
                int id = rs.getInt("id");
                String username = rs.getString("username");
                String firstname = rs.getString("firstname");
                String lastname = rs.getString("lastname");
                String email = rs.getString("email");
                String gender = rs.getString("gender");
                String description = rs.getString("description");
                String createdon = rs.getString("createdon");
                String editedon = rs.getString("editedon");
                String active = rs.getString("active");

                person = new Person(id,username,firstname,lastname,email,gender,description,createdon,editedon,active);
                data.add(person);
            }
            st.close();
        } catch(Exception  e) {
            System.out.println("There is an Exception.");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        idColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));
        usernameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("username"));
        firstnameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstname"));
        lastnameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastname"));
        emailColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("email"));
        genderColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("gender"));
        descColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("description"));
        createdonColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("createdon"));
        editedonColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("editedon"));
        activeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("active"));

        tableUsers.setItems(data);

    }

}
```